# Umbraco Models Builder throwing error on Run Custom Tool

Tags: c#, umbraco, models

I am trying to work with Umbraco Models Builder with the following settings in web.config -

```
 <add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Enable" value="true" />
 <add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.EnableApi" value="true" />
```

I have installed ModelsBuilder.Api nuget pakage as well.

I am generating the models in a seperate project and when I run custom tool I get the following error -

**UmbracoModelsBuilder: UmbracoModelsBuilder failed to generate code: Exception: Response status code does not indicate success (Unauthorized)**

I have added the credentials in ModelBuilder options as well (Tools-> Options-> Umbraco-> ModelsBuilder options).

Can someone help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: it may sound stupid, but was the credential you set in the option have enough permission?  if it is not admin, give it admin permission

Comment: You've probably already seen it but this article has some good info on the API Models set-up: https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2016/getting-started-with-modelsbuilder/

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I was generating the models when the project was not in a running state. Silly me ! Its working now. I followed this same article later on :)